# Home directory paths in Unity Launcher

Tags: command-line, launcher

I am trying to have a relative path to my home directory in my launcher script.

Example (working):

```
Exec=terminator -x /home/patrick/Dropbox/System/Scripts/belzebub2hanibal.sh
```

Example (not working):

```
Exec=terminator -x ~/Dropbox/System/Scripts/belzebub2hanibal.sh
```

Is there any way to use variables for the home directory of the current user in a Launcher script?

Comment: The variable $HOME isn't good ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$HOME` instead of `~` (tilde).

Tilde is bash specific. In bash tilde expands to the value of `$HOME`. Outside of bash tilde has no special meaning.

Read the [bash manual about tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion) for more details.

Comment: $HOME is working, thank you. I did not know about the tildes bash specifity.